# What was Aida’s real plan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

After Fitz refuses to "choose" Aida, she devises a plan to make him and S.H.I.E.L.D. suffer, and to restore her to power of the sort she enjoyed as Madame Hydra in the Framework.

Some quotes make it seem like she has some supernatural plan to supplant the world outside the Framework with one similar to the one inside:

> SUPERIOR: I can make you feel something else. That book helps build
> worlds. My plan will rebuild the world that you have grown accustomed
> to, one where Inhumans are hunted.
>
> <sub>*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, “The Return”</sub>

Similarly, in the next episode:

> AIDA: I want to burn this world to the ground.
>
> SUPERIOR: I thought you wanted to rule it?
>
> AIDA: Don’t mistake my anger for recklessness:  The Darkhold has shown us *exactly* what to do.
>
> <sub>*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, “World’s End”</sub>

Any plan she had with the Darkhold would seem to have been stalled by her untimely immolation.

On the other hand, in the finale she appears to be executing the perfectly *mundane* plan of stirring up anger against Inhumans with a false flag attack, one that didn’t seem to require any use of the Darkhold at all (just a Daisy LMD and one of the bodies that the Superior already had lying around).

What *was* Aida’s plan? And how did the Darkhold factor into it, if at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Darkhold was necessary to corrupt the other people at the meeting as Ivanov is trying to get them to look at it before all hell broke loose. Beyond that it's vague, likely because the writers knew there'd be no need to elaborate on it because the plan would be foiled, so there was no need to create an elaborate explanation for no reason.